# Dojo 118n resource construct; why?

Tags: javascript, dojo

In dojo 1.9 source, dijit/nls/common.js I see this

```
define({ root:    
({
    buttonOk: "OK",
    buttonCancel: "Cancel",
    buttonSave: "Save",
    itemClose: "Close"
})

//etc
```

why has the author used the

```
( { /*data*/ } )
```

construct? What does this actually mean? Why are {} not sufficient? The () are presumably delimiting an expression, but why is it necessary to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any reason in that particular example.

But in some cases...

> (Note that you may need to wrap the object literal in parentheses if the object appears where a statement is expected, so as not to have the literal be confused with a block statement.)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

`eval()` probably has something to do with it, but in your particular example, the JS parser should be dealing with the code and there should be no used of `eval()`.

E.g. (no parentheses):

```
SyntaxError: invalid label

eval("{a:1, b:2}")
```

and (with parentheses):

```
>>> eval("({a:1, b:2})")
Object { a=1, b=2}
```

Maybe it has something to do with Dojo's build process, and the NLS module is reformatted to need the parentheses? Seems unlikely as that seems brittle and the build process itself could just as easily add the parentheses.

---

**EDIT**: I've just taken a look at the history of this file on GitHub.

The original version (in GitHub - https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/11f94ad6cebba102b8411ed1a67e35aed94a97bb/nls/common.js) looks like this:

```
({
    buttonOk: "OK",
    buttonCancel: "Cancel",
    buttonSave: "Save",

    notSet: "Not set",
    left: "Left",
    right: "Right",
    center: "Center",
    middle: "Middle",
    top: "Top",
    bottom: "Bottom",

    //units
    unitPixel: "pixels",
    unitPercent: "percent",
    width: "Width",
    height: "Height"
})
```

So I would guess this file was originally `eval`'d, and the parentheses were historically necessary, but became somewhat redundant with the move to AMD.

Could be wrong of course!